# VAADIN-GRID V2 and POLYMER Adding Grid-Detail

Tags: polymer, vaadin-grid

I am starting with Polymer Starter-kit and Vaadin-grid V2-beta

I can get this code to display, but having trouble showing a Row details.
The effect I am going for looks like:
https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-core-elements/master/vaadin-grid/demo/other.html
Row details

This code I took from example, and its working.  Could someone mark this up and add how the detail would be done please

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">

<dom-module id="my-view6">
  <template>
    <style include="shared-styles">
      :host {
        display: block;

        padding: 10px;
      }
    </style>

    <vaadin-grid items='[{"name": "John", "surname": "Lennon", "role": "singer"}, 
                          {"name": "Ringo", "surname": "Starr", "role": "drums"},
                          {"name": "John", "surname": "Lennon", "role": "singer"}, 
                          {"name": "Ringo", "surname": "Starr", "role": "drums"},
                          {"name": "John", "surname": "Lennon", "role": "singer"},
                          {"name": "John", "surname": "Lennon", "role": "singer"}, 
                          {"name": "Ringo", "surname": "Starr", "role": "drums"},
                          {"name": "John", "surname": "Lennon", "role": "singer"},
                          {"name": "Ringo", "surname": "Starr", "role": "drums"},
                          {"name": "John", "surname": "Lennon", "role": "singer"},                                              
                          {"name": "Ringo", "surname": "Starr", "role": "drums"}]'>

          <vaadin-grid-column-group>
            <vaadin-grid-column>
              <template class="header">Name</template>
              <template>[[item.name]]</template>
            </vaadin-grid-column>
            <vaadin-grid-column>
              <template class="header">Surname</template>
              <template>[[item.surname]]</template>
            </vaadin-grid-column>
          </vaadin-grid-column-group>

          <vaadin-grid-column>
            <template class="header">Role</template>
            <template>[[item.role]]</template>
          </vaadin-grid-column>
        </vaadin-grid>
      </template>

      <script>
        Polymer({
          is: 'my-view6',
        });
      </script>
    </dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two things:

First, add a template with the detail contents

```
<template class="row-details">
  <div>My Details</div>
</template>
```

Second, toggle the details either by using `{{expanded}}` variable, `expandedItems` property or the `expandItem(item)` and `collapseItem(item)` API.

See the example here: https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-grid/2.0.0-alpha2/demo/#row-details